# Do we have contextlib equivalent api in python 2 version which can do or somehow manage the contextlib api

Tags: python

we have earlier version of python 2.7 in our production machine and we do not want to upgrade the python in our machine but we need the contextlib in our existing python 2 version so do we have any other API which is we can use in our python 2 version .
Please let me know if any one have idea or suggestion to achieve the contextlib.

Comment: I’m confused? [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) exists since Python 2.5, so maybe point out *what exactly* you need from it that’s missing in Python 2?

Comment: Also: [contextlib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/contextlib2) ([docs](https://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).